# Give me a direct link to the revision history in the Activity tab

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, recent-activity

**Background**

In the *Activity* tab on the *User Profile* page, it is possible to see revisions made by the user.

Currently the links for the revisions point to the actual posts (that is to the questions / answers that were revised). This is demonstrated by the blue arrow below in the screen capture - it points to a post title, which is a link to the post itself.

**Rationale Behind This Feature Request**

I was looking at the *Interesting* tab tonight on Stack Overflow and saw a bunch of posts modified by the same user. I wanted to investigate to see if his activities were legitimate, so I went to that user's recent activity tab to look at his revision history. The problem was that I had to click on the post link there, and when I arrived at the post itself, click on the revision history link.

Doing this for many posts is not efficient, and therefore...

**The Feature Request**

I'd the *Activity* tab to also link to the actual revisions that the user made. Perhaps the "revised" text (red arrow below) could point to the revision?

Just as an example, clicking on the revised link on the first item below would go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15844170/revisions) - ideally the link would go to the actual revision on the revisions page.

---

[image: activity-revisions]

---